# AWS serverless websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, serverless

Anyone ever got an error when opening a web socket connection on AWS serverless?
I tested the connection on web-socket.org and my browser is good, but when I open the connection to my API it fails and I get an undefined error so I checked the error in Chome dev tools. Got a 502 error code.
My lambda functions are permissioned appropriately through my administrative role defined in the serverless.yml through a Iam role.  Please help me lol I will cash app you $1.15 if you help me lol  everything else is perfect

Comment: Why $1.15 ?? :)

Comment: I was joking. I really need to figure this out lol